# Android - focus navigation back button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, focus, back-button

I have the following view:

[image: Verification View]

when I click on one of the edit texts a soft keyboard appears. After closing this keyboard my navigation back button doesn't react when i click it. Before I click on one of the edit texts my back button works fine.

The code of my "verification" fragment:

```
class VerifyPhoneFragment : Fragment() {

lateinit var appContext: Context
private var editTexts: ArrayList<EditText> = ArrayList()
private var focusedElement: Int = 0
private var verifyButton: TextView? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_verify_phone, container, false)

    val backButton = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.backButtonAbout)
    backButton.setOnClickListener {
        activity!!.onBackPressed()
    }

    verifyButton = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_verify)
    verifyButton?.setOnClickListener {
        val dataConnection = DataConnection()
        var code: String = ""
        editTexts.forEach {
            code += it.text.toString()
        }

        dataConnection.doGet("/phone/verification",
                hashMapOf("token" to code),
                { result: Any?, message: String ->
                    activity!!.runOnUiThread {
                        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        if(result != null && result is Boolean && result)
                            activity!!.onBackPressed()
                    }

                }, Boolean::class.java)
    }


    editTexts.add(view.findViewById(R.id.editText1))
    editTexts.add(view.findViewById(R.id.editText2))
    editTexts.add(view.findViewById(R.id.editText3))
    editTexts.add(view.findViewById(R.id.editText4))
    editTexts.add(view.findViewById(R.id.editText5))
    editTexts.add(view.findViewById(R.id.editText6))

    editTexts.forEach { et ->
        et.isEnabled = false
        et.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener {
            override fun onKey(v: View, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.action !=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if((focusedElement > 0 && focusedElement != 5) || (focusedElement == 5 && editTexts[focusedElement].text.toString().length == 0)) {
                        focusedElement--
                        editTexts[focusedElement].isEnabled = true
                        editTexts[focusedElement].requestFocus()
                        editTexts[focusedElement].setText("")
                        editTexts[focusedElement+1].isEnabled = false
                    }
                    else if(focusedElement == 5 && editTexts[focusedElement].text.toString().length != 0){
                        editTexts[focusedElement].setText("")
                    }
                }
                else if(keyCode >= 7 && keyCode <= 16 && event.action !=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    if(focusedElement < 5)
                    {
                        editTexts[focusedElement].setText((keyCode - 7).toString())
                        focusedElement++
                        editTexts[focusedElement].isEnabled = true
                        editTexts[focusedElement].requestFocus()
                        editTexts[focusedElement-1].isEnabled = false
                    }
                    else {
                        editTexts[focusedElement].setText((keyCode - 7).toString())
                        editTexts[focusedElement].clearFocus()
                        hideKeyboard(editTexts[focusedElement])
                    }
                }
                checkIfVerifyShouldBeEnabled()
                return true
            }
        })
    }
    editTexts[focusedElement].isEnabled = true

    return view
}

private fun hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    val imm = view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}

private fun checkIfVerifyShouldBeEnabled(){
    if(editTexts[5].text.toString().length > 0) {
        verifyButton?.isEnabled = true
        verifyButton?.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
    }
    else{
        verifyButton?.isEnabled = false
        verifyButton?.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.grey))
    }

}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    appContext = context!!
}
}
```

The code of my layout for this fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background_payment_1">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/backButtonAbout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_verify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="@string/verify"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:enabled="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:text="@string/verification_code"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    style="@style/ToolBarHeaderText"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.49"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/message_phone_verification"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#76FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cv2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv2"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#76FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cv3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cv1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv3"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#76FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cv4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cv2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv4"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#76FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cv5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cv3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv5"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#76FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cv6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cv4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:inputType="number">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv6"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#76FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cv5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So my question is, how do I get the focus of my navigation back button? Or is it a focus problem at all? 
Btw, the cancel button always works fine!

Comment: _back button_ means navigation back button?

Comment: yes i mean the navigation button. Already updated my question

Comment: Might be it cause the focus issue. What have you set _softWindowInput_?

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Check with _adjustPan_

Comment: adjustPan does not work too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185061/discussion-between-piyush-and-sabina).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. When the user manually closes the keyboard the focus is still on the current edit text. So when he then presses the navigation back button the onKey event is fired, but i didn't handle the back key event. 
So i just added following code and everything works fine:

```
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.action != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
     activity?.onBackPressed()
}
```